# AngularJS $http request using jsonp to a html page?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to retrieve the html page as data in my success callback function to I can get access to the meta tags of the website I'm requesting to. I get an error "MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled". I don't get why it doesn't work, because  the return object I get if I enable corse on my browser using plain $http is a javascript object (logged onto my console). So why can't jsonp simply return the headers of any website such as https://www.youtube.com/. Am I missing something really important here?!

```js
var url = "https://www.facebook.com/";

$http.jsonp(url).
    success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).
    error(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: I'm afraid what you're trying to achieve cannot be done.

JSONP expects the response type to be `application/javascript`, but https://www.facebook.com will respond with `text/html`, thus not being compatible (executable). More on JSONP here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP.

What you could use is `$http.get(url)`, which accepts any mime type, BUT that will be denied by modern browsers implementing CORS policy. The error will be `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` or similar. You are not allowed to request a resource out of your own domain unless specifically allowed by the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response headers. Facebook will not have the headers allowing you to fetch content via XHR, thus you will not get the response.

I highly suggest you to read how CORS works - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS. Will save you a lot of hassle in the future.

Comment: I just have one question. If $http.get returns text/html than why does it return a javascript object? for example If I bypass corse and log the response to my console I get this response `Object {data: "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" data-cast-api-enabl…si.tick("jl", null, '');}</script>↵</body></html>", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}`. Is that not javascript?

Comment: Cause internally indirectly or directly Angular parses the original HTTP response (which is just plain text) into JavaScript object for ease-of-use. Your actual HTTP response body is parsed into ``data`` property, HTTP status code into ``status``, HTTP status text into ``statusText`` and so on.